# How do I ask for an advanced topic to a Prof?

Tags: undergraduate, research-undergraduate, projects

I asked a prof for a project and he gave me a book to read. However, I am already familiar with its content(I did an online course). I want to request him to change my topic.

Is it okay to ask for a change? How should I do it?

Comment: more details please. Is this a thesis?

Comment: @quantum It is a undergraduate project

Comment: The title mentions an advanced topic, the body of your question only a different topic. Which is it?

Comment: Taking an online course and thoroughly working through a book are two different things.